# How do I change page numbers to words?

Tags: wp-link-pages

So I need to change the page numbers to word but I can't figures out how to do it. Right now I'm using page breaks but it always looks like the example below no matter how many times I try to fix it, sigh....

**Example: Instead of saying 1 2 3 4 5
I need it to say Appetizers, Salads, Combos, Sandwiches, Burgers**

PLEASE HELP ME!!!

Comment: The pages of a post don't have names, pagination just lists them numerically, not because a page is titled page 2, but because that's just the order it appeared in. What you want is not possible this way. Are you sure you don't want child-pages instead and links to those child pages? Note this stack is not for general support, but a programming stack, and there is no code in your question

Comment: What are child-pages? I'm just trying to make a menu for my restaurant look nice

Comment: when you create a page, you can set a parent page in the sidebar, e.g. if I have `foo` and `bar` pages, I can tell WP that `foo` is the parent of `bar`, then create a list of links. The page breaks/more tag that creates pagination isn't what you want and can't be used to create a menu navigation. Instead you want a Sandwiches page, and a Burgers page, and a Salads page, etc